# How are $ \exists x (P(x) ⊕ Q(x)) $ and $(\exists x P(x)) ⊕ (\exists x Q(x))$ not logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I want to know how these two statements are not logically equivalent. From what I have done I am getting them as logically equivalent. I have started as letting $P(x) = x$ is even and $Q(y) = y$ is odd.

For your convience if you want to copy the question $\exists x(P(x) ⊕ Q(x))$ and (\exists x P(x)) ⊕ (\exist x Q(x))$

⊕ = exclusive or

Comment: Would the first one not say there exists a number that is either even or odd? I think I maybe wrong here? Oh ⊕ is exclusive or. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: Maybe I'm confused.  What does $\oplus$ mean?  I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: ⊕ = exclusive or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 4 is even and not odd.  Therefore $P(4) \oplus Q(4)$ is true.  Therefore $\exists x(P(x) \oplus Q(x))$ is true, as witnessed by $x=4$.

$\exists x P(x)$ is true, as witnessed by $x=4$.  $\exists x Q(x)$ is true, as witnessed by $x=3$.  Since both are true, $(\exists x P(x)) \oplus (\exists x Q(x))$ is false.

Since one statement is true and the other is false, they are not logically equivalent.

Comment: I need a bit more help in understanding the second part/statement

Comment: It's the same type of argument as before.  $P(4)$ is true.  Therefore $\exists x P(x)$ is true: there does exist an $x$ such that $P(x)$; namely $x=4$.  Likewise, $Q(3)$ is true and so $\exists x Q(x)$ is true.  There is no requirement that they be the same $x$!  Occurrences of the same variable, in this case $x$, in different $\exists$-clauses need not refer to the same specific element.  In programming terms, $x$ is a local variable whose scope is only the expression following $\exists x$.

Comment: I see because both statements are true thus 1⊕1 is false.

Answer (score 0):

> How are ∃x(P(x) ⊕ Q(x)) and (∃xP(x)) ⊕ (∃xQ(x)) not logically equivalent?

The first states that there exists something for which either P or Q holds but not both.

The second states there either exists something for which P holds, or there exists something for which Q holds, but both do not exist.

---

By way of counter example, let's talk about integers.  Let P(x) be the statement that an integer is odd. Let Q(x) be the statement that an integer is even.

There exists at least one integer which is either odd or even but not both at once.  That is all of them, in fact. So ∃x(P(x) ⊕ Q(x)) holds.

It isn't so that you can either find an odd integer, or an even integer, but you cannot find an example of both.  So (∃xP(x)) ⊕ (∃xQ(x)) does not hold.

Hence the statements cannot be equivalent.